# 〜ような or 〜ように before V-stem + 方

Tags: grammar, particle-に, nominalization, na-adjectives, particle-な

I encountered the following multiple-choice question in a JLPT N3 grammar practice test:

> 仕事と生活の（　　　）働き方がしたい。
>
> １　バランスをとるらしく　　　　　２　バランスをとるらしい
>
> ３　バランスがとれるような　　　　４　バランスがとれるように

I chose 「３　バランスがとれるような」, but the answer given is 「４　バランスがとれるように」.

I understood the sentence to mean "I would like to work in such a way that I can maintain a balance between work and life."  I am under the impression that 働き方 is a noun, so I used 〜ような to modify it.  Why is the answer 〜ように instead of 〜ような?

Comment: 4 doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @EddieKal Thanks for the confirmation.  The practice test was taken from an app (JLPT テスト) instead of a published book, so I am starting to suspect that this is a typo in the app.

Comment: I agree, the correct answer is 3.